# Saving an object updates all the fields even when `updatable=false` in SpringJPA

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, jpa

I have an class called `Credential` which has field called `User`. Here is the class,

```
@Entity
public class Credential extends BaseModel {

    // more fields

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_cred", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cred_id", 
    updatable = false, insertable = true), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", updatable = false, 
    insertable = true))
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;

    // setters getters
}
```

I also have a service class which I am using to save this object of this `Credential` class. Now the user class is having a field `Key` which I don't want to update if I am saving a new `Credential` object.
Here is the `User` class,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends BaseModel {

    // more fields
   
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = AESKey.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "password_id", updatable = false, insertable = true)
    private Key password;

    // getter setter
}
```

I have used `updatable=false` in both `User` field in`Credential` and `Key` field in `User`. Even then when I am saving the `Credential` object, `Key` object is also updated.
I have tried removing `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` but the result is the same.
Here is the query that runs everytime I save the `Credential` object,

```
Hibernate: insert into credential (creation_date, associated_phone_number, email, password, username, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into user_cred (user_id, cred_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: update key set creation_date=?, key=?, type=? where id=?
```

I dont want to add `updatable=false` to my fields in `Key` class as then I will be forbidden to update my `Key` objects *directly*. I just want to prevent *indirect* updations.

Can anyone tell how prevent my `Key` object from updating.

Comment: You can remove the field `key` in the query, so the field won't be updated.

Comment: From which query? I didn't understand the solution.

Comment: Do you have a `sql` file where you initialize your queries with an Update statement?

Comment: No. I am not using any sql file. Totally dependent on hibernate